# iOS app that collects data from "Accu-Chek Aviva Connect" BG meter. (Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to create an iOS app that will collect data from **Accu-Chek Aviva Connect**.

To pair with BG meter I send a write request to Record Access Control Point Characteristic:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {

    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1808"]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {

            // Read Glucose Measurement...

            // Read Glucose Measurement Context...

            // Read Glucose Feature...

            // Read Date Time...

            // Read Record Access Control Point
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A52"]]) {
                [aPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
                [aPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];

                uint8_t bytes[] = {0x04, 0x01, 0x00};
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

                [aPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And on iPhone I see a UIAlert with a field to enter the security code. And I'm able to pair iPhone with **Accu-Chek Aviva Connect**. But the next time I send some write request to *Record Access Control Poin* Characteristic (after device disconnected) I get **"Error: Authentication is insufficient"** and no UIAlert on iPhone.

I have a feeling that I'm doing everything wrong.

I want to read records from bluetooth device's log. AFAIU I write bytes to Read Record Access Control Point (`[aPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];`) and get answer in `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:`. But I can't do it because **"Error: Authentication is insufficient"** stands in my way!

Comment: You should post the code that throws the "authentication is insufficient".  I'm curious if it's coming from iOS or the device itself?  Also, where is the Aviva Connect API described or found?  It's not easily Google-able...

Comment: There is no official documentation for Accu-Chek. But it uses official Bluetooth Glucose Service: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.glucose.xml

Comment: If you have paired the device and entered the PIN then the device should show up in the list of bluetooth devices in the Settings->Bluetooth.My Devices. Does it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to work with Accu-Chek Aviva Connect is to pair it the first time by going to `Settings` → `Wireless` → `Pairing` → `Pair Device`.
Then you get a screen with number code and a message: *"Enter code on device"*.

On iPhone you discover Accu-Chek device and write a value to Read Record Access Control Point characteristic. For example request a Number of records:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {

    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1808"]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {

            // Read Record Access Control Point
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A52"]]) {
                [aPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
                [aPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];

                self.readAccessControlPointCharacteristic = aChar;

                NSMutableData *mutableData = [NSMutableData data];
                uint8_t opCode = 0x04; // Report number of stored records
                uint8_t operator = 0x01; // All records

                [mutableData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&opCode length:sizeof(opCode)]];
                [mutableData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&operator length:sizeof(operator)]];

                [aPeripheral writeValue:mutableData forCharacteristic:self.readAccessControlPointCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            }

        }
    }
```

This leads to an UIAlertView on iPhone where it asks you to enter a code which is displayed on Accu-Chek screen. When you do it, **your iPhone will be successfully paired** with Accu-Chek Aviva Connect.

Now. When you want to read all records from Bluetooth device - you will have to go to `My Data` → `Data Transfer` → `Wireless` → and if your Accu-Chek device has a lot of pairings, select your iPhone name. *Note:* iPhone must be scaning for BT devices and connect to a discovered device automatically.

Bluetooth connection will be established and you can send any requests from your iPhone to Bluetooth device without *"Error: Authentication is insufficient"*!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be authenticated to issue a write request to the BG meter. Insufficient authentication means that you are trying to issue the request without being authenticated. You can't just connect and then write to a medically relevant characteristic.

Check if you really issue an authentication request (which would also require a PIN entry). And if yes, check if the PIN is accepted or rejected.